# Magento 2 - Products not showing in front end

Tags: magento2, product, category, frontend

I have an issue with my development store (Magento 2.2.7), I have cleaned all data from the database with this tutorial (https://www.titechglobal.com/magento-2-x-how-to-clear-test-data-before-production/).

Now, in the backend, my products / categories appears correctly but from the frontend, my products are not showing in the category pages but I can access to the product page with the direct link and also nothing appears when I type my product name in the search bar.

I run this command on my server :

`rm -rf var/di var/generation`

- php bin/magento cache:clean
- php bin/magento cache:flush
- php bin/magento setup:upgrade
- php bin/magento setup:di:compile
- php bin/magento indexer:reindex
- php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

But nothing solved my issue. I found something strange, my table `catalog_category_product_index` is empty but I don't know why.

Can you help me??

Comment: your products are not in the category, assign products to the category then they will show.

Comment: The products are assigned in the category. From the back end, when I go to the category, in the "Products in category" tab, I see all products..

Comment: Did you check your logs ?

Comment: No, where I can check my logs?

Comment: In `var/log/` you have `system.log` and `exception.log`. You also have may be some reports in `var/report`.

Comment: I have this error : [2019-07-24 08:08:25] main.WARNING: Attempt to load value of nonexistent EAV attribute '42' 
                        for entity type 'Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\CategoryInterface'. [] []

Comment: Did you create new attributes for your categories ? In `eav_attribute` do you have a row with entity_id = 42?

Comment: In eav_attribute I have a row with attribute_id=42. Before to clean all data, I created an attribute set with 10 attributes and the products are linked to this attribute set. Do you think that my issue is due to this error ?

Comment: Tu viens de France Kozame?

Comment: @VP13 Mon anglais est si mauvais que ça ? ^^" Là j'ai l'impression que ta catégorie essaye de charger un attribut qui n'existe pas

Comment: @Kozame Non non j'ai vu dans ton profil.. Pourtant je n'ai pas touché à la partie "Attribut". Mes catégories sont créer automatiquement à partir de mon ERP qui est connecté à ma boutique via une API, j'ai essayé de créer une nouvelle "Root Category" avec une "Sub Category" et un nouvel article manuellement mais pareil, rien ne s'affiche.. Est-ce que tu penses que c'est normal que ma table "catalog_category_product_index" soit vide?? Car dans ma base de données de backup, la table n'est pas vide..

Comment: A quoi correspond ton attribut dont l'id est 42 ? Ma table `catalog_category_product_index` est vide également, mais j'ai des tables `catalog_category_product_index_storex` qui elles sont remplies. Je ne sais donc pas si c'est lié.
Si tu compares ta backuup et ta base actuelle, tu obtiens les mêmes données sur la ligne 42 ?

Comment: @Kozame J'ai essayé de restaurer ma base de données de backup et mes articles s'affiche correctement, je pense qu'il y a un soucis quand je supprime toutes les données à partir de la base de données pour avoir une instance vierge.

Comment: L'attribut 42 est "failures_num", après j'ai mis que l'erreur avec l'id 42 mais j'en ai plusieurs (43, 44, 113, 114) dans mon fichier de log. Et oui, j'ai les mêmes données pour les attributs entre mes deux bases de données.

Comment: @Kozame Tu as peut-être une autre méthode pour supprimer toutes les données de ma base de développement (produits, catégories, clients, commandes, recherches,...)

Comment: Une fois ta backup restaurée, tes erreurs continuent à s'afficher dans tes logs ou pas ? (pour être sûr que le problème vient bien de là)
Je n'ai jamais fait de reset de base de données, alors je ne suis pas sûr d'être la mieux placée à ce niveau là pour t'aider :/

Comment: Pour le moment ça ne s'affiche plus mais le log d'erreur pour les attributs est d'aujourd'hui à 8h08, et j'ai fais plusieurs tests depuis 8h08.. Ok pas de soucis, c'est déjà bien, je vais essayé de trouver une autre procédure pour vider mes données.

Answer (score 0):

- You can run the following commands:

`php bin/magento setup:upgrade`

`php bin/magento indexer:reindex`

`php bin/magento cache:flush`

- Check list:

1: The products must be Visible in Catalog.

2: The products must be Enabled.

3: Product must have a stock Quantity.

4: The product must be set to In Stock.

5: If the product is set not to track stock, it still has to have a stock Quantity and be set to In Stock.

6: The product must be assigned to the target Category.

7: If using multi-website mode (or if you imported the products through Data Flow), the products must be assigned to the target Website. (check table catalog_product_website)

8: You must refresh your Cache / Indices, just to make sure.(php bin/magento cache:flush )